# What is go: in main.go

Tags: go, terraform

I'm new to golang, and am noticing instances in main.go files of packages where there is a commented section that has a `go:[command]`. I.e. in Terraform packages if I add the snippet below to my main.go file and enter `go generate ./...` in my terminal the command under the tfplugindocs is run. What is this feature in golang called and how does it work?

```golang
// Generate the Terraform provider documentation using `tfplugindocs`:
//go:generate go run github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-docs/cmd/tfplugindocs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are directives. See [the compile docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/compile) and [this blog post](https://go.dev/blog/generate) on `generate`. How it works is documented [in the source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/generate/generate.go#L38), but in short, `generate` scans files for that directive, parses it according to the rules specified at the line linked above, and eventually [runs the command](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/generate/generate.go#L475). There are other directives, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/golang/website/commit/de15dbe30dfb3bde6040b510e6c38068fa30167a) (and also [on the actual site, but the site doesn't have section anchors so it's harder to find](https://tip.golang.org/doc/comment)).

Answer (score 0):

Those special comment lines are known as directives or pragmas. The generate directive is documented at https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source. This [article](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/01/08/gos-hidden-pragmas) discusses most of them.